# Import "Framework" is possible but unable to access the classes from the custom framework in swift 3

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift3, swift-custom-framework

I have created a custom swift framework named "TestFramework" .
I created a new swift Project "TestProject" and added TestFramework to the project.

While importing, the "TestFramework" is listed in autosuggest.

ISSUE 1 :

Right Click on import TestFramework -> Jump To Definition ->
[image]

ISSUE 2:
The Classes in the TestFramework are all having Public access specifiers.

But I am not able able to access the classes in the Project

Comment: Is your framework written in Objective-C? Can you link to the test project/workspace?